# Не работает CSS на конкретного ребенка от класса родителя

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени! Потребовалось мне сверстать красивую таблицу, основная таблица тег table имеет класс generaltable вот так

```
<table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" class="generaltable">
<tr>
<td> 
....
```

И так далее там дальше много столбцов и строк, при том в таблице в некоторых ячейках тоже есть таблицы

мне нужно задать в первой строке (tr) у первой ячейки (td) height через css
делаю вот так:

```
.generaltable tr:nth-child(1) td {
height: 100px;
}
```

Но проблема в том что таким образом даже у второстепенных таблиц первая td наследует это свойство делаю вот так что бы конкретней было:

```
.generaltable > tr:nth-child(1) td {
height: 100px;
}
```

но тогда вообще перестает работать конструкция, подскажите где я ошибся?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дело в том, что браузер добавляет тег [tbody](http://htmlbook.ru/html/tbody) между table и tr.

```css
.generaltable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" class="generaltable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td> 
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```